# Search for 1-D sequence in multidimensional array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, find

I have an array with n dimensions, and I have a sequence along one dimension at a certain location on all other dimensions. How do I find the location of this sequence? Preferably without loops.

I use matlab. I know what dimension it should be in, but the sequence isnt necessarily there. Find and == dont work. I could make an nd find function using crosscorrelation but Im guessing this is already implemented and I just dont know what function to call.

example:

```
ND = rand(10,10,10,10);
V = ND(randi(10),randi(10),randi(10),:);
[I1, I2, I3] = find(ND==V);
```

Edit: The sequence to be found spans the entire dimension it is on, I did not mention this in my original formulation of the problem. Knedlsepp`s solution solves exactly the problem I had, but Luis' solution solves a more general problem for when the sequence doesn't necessarily span the entire dimension.

Comment: Have you tried with correlation? I guess you can correlate the sequence with the matrix and the point with highest corr (if it is exactly equal corr=1) will be the one you want. This way you will be able to see if the sequence is repeated in different places also.

Comment: Do you already know which dimension you are looking along (eg in the example you gave, do you know to look along the third dimension?)

Comment: Yes I do know the dimension

Comment: Bit off-topic, but instead of `round(10*rand)` you should use `randi(10)`. As the first one will yield integers from 0 to 10.

Comment: Is it possible that the pattern doesn't appear once? For example: `ND = [1 2 1 2; 3 4 5 6]`, `V = [1 2]`, search along 2nd dim

Comment: I dont know who edited the title, but people who search " Find vector in nd array " wont easily find this answer, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there are multiple ways to interpret your question, I will clarify: This approach assumes a 1D sequence of size: `numel(V) == size(ND, dimToSearch)`. So, for `V = [1,2]` and `ND = [1,2,1,2]` it is not applicable. If you want this functionality go with *Luis Mendo*'s answer, if not this will likely be faster.

This will be a perfect opportunity to use `bsxfun`:

We start with some example data:

```
ND = rand(10,10,10,10);
V = ND(3,2,:,3);
```

If you don't have the vector `V` given in the correct dimension (in this case `[1,1,10,1]`) you can reshape it in the following way:

```
dimToSearch = 3;
Vdims = ones(1, ndims(ND)); 
Vdims(dimToSearch) = numel(V);
V = reshape(V, Vdims);
```

Now we generate a cell that will hold the indices of the matches:

```
I = cell(1, ndims(ND));
```

At this point we compute the size of `ND` if it were collapsed along the dimension `dimToSearch` (we compute `dimToSearch` according to `V`, as at this point it will have the correct dimensions):

```
dimToSearch = find(size(V)>1);
collapsedDims = size(ND); 
collapsedDims(dimToSearch) = 1;
```

Finally the part where we actually look for the pattern:

```
[I{:}] = ind2sub(collapsedDims, find(all(bsxfun(@eq, ND, V), dimToSearch)));
```

This is done in the following way: `bsxfun(@eq, ND, V)` will implicitly `repmat` the array `V` so it has the same dimensions as `ND` and do an equality comparison. After this we do a check with `all` to see if all the entries in the dimension `dimToSearch` are equal. The calls to `find` and `ind2sub` will then generate the correct indices to your data.

Comment: `dim` could be replaced with `find(size(V)>1)` for a generic one?

Comment: Generally my arrays have n>3

Comment: Does this really work? I'm trying with `ND = [1 2 1 4; 3 1 2 6], V = [1 2]` and getting an error (maybe I understood the question wrongly)

Comment: @Leo: You will have to use `ind2sub` there. Give me a sec.

Comment: @LuisMendo: Let me read the question again. I was given the impression that `V` would be given in the correct way (`V = [1;2]`)

Comment: Yes I know the dimension to look in so it would be [1;2] in that example

Comment: Could you also explain a little in your final answer? Its difficult to interpret 4 nested functions.

Comment: @Leo: This should work now. Bare in mind that *Luis Mendo*'s answer is more general, as it can find multiple occurences of the data in the same dimension. For example with the data `ND = [1,2,1,2]` and `V=[1,2]` it would find two occurrences. This approach will throw an error. The upside is, that whenever this approach is applicable, it should be fast.

Comment: Your interpretation of the question turned out to be correct +1

Answer (score 2):

Let `d` be the dimension along which to search. I'm assuming that the sought sequence `V` may be shorter than `size(ND,d)`. So the sequence may appear once, more than once, or never along each dimension-`d`- "thread".

The following code uses [`num2cell`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) to reshape `ND` into a cell array such that each dimension-`d`-thread is in a different cell. Then [`strfind`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) is applied to each cell to determine matches with `V`, and the result is a cell array with the same dimensions as `ND`, but where the dimension `d` is a singleton. The contents of each cell tell the `d`-dimension-positions of the matches, if any.

Credit goes to @knedlsepp for his suggestion to use `num2cell`, which greatly simplified the code.

```
ND = cat(3, [1 2 1 2; 3 4 5 6],[2 1 0 5; 0 0 1 2] ); %// example. 2x4x2
V = 1:2; %// sought pattern. It doesn't matter if it's a row, or a column, or...
d = 2; %// dimension along which to search for pattern V
result = cellfun(@(x) strfind(x(:).', V(:).'), num2cell(ND,d), 'UniformOutput', 0);
```

This gives

```
ND(:,:,1) =
     1     2     1     2
     3     4     5     6
ND(:,:,2) =
     2     1     0     5
     0     0     1     2

V =
     1     2

result{1,1,1} =
     1     3    %// V appears twice (at cols 1 and 3) in 1st row, 1st slice
result{2,1,1} =
     []         %// V doesn't appear in 2nd row, 1st slice
result{1,1,2} =
     []         %// V appears appear in 1st row, 2nd slice
result{2,1,2} =
     3          %// V appears once (at col 3) in 2nd row, 2nd slice
```

Comment: Oh! I just now understood what you meant by your comment to my answer! I thought the OP was given a pattern of size `numel(V) == size(ND, d)`!

Comment: @knedlsepp And now I see what your answer was doing, and why it could be done so simply :-) Well, we'll see what the OP really wanted. The question was not very clear indeed

Comment: After stepping through your solution to understand what's going on, I think you might be able to simplify by using `result = cellfun(@(x) strfind(x(:).', V(:).'), num2cell(ND,d), 'uni', 0)`

Comment: @knedlsepp Good one! I always forget about `num2cell`. It simplifies things a lot in this case. I think you should make it a separate answer! Or add it to your answer, that is

Comment: Hmm I also just now understand what you meant by your comment on noodlesoup s answer. The sequence I am looking for spans the entire dimension it is on, however it can occur in multiple coordinates of the remaining dimensions. You both gave great answers, Im inclined to accept knedlsepp s for my current problem. Although Im sure myself and others will encounter problems where your solution is needed.

Comment: @Leo Yes, in that case knedlsepp's answer does what you want. I've edited my answer to reflect my interpretation of the question.

Comment: @LuisMendo: I made an edit to include `num2cell` in your answer, as I don't want to take the credit for what was essentially your idea. :-)

Comment: @knedlsepp I've also added a link to `num2cell` and due credit

Answer (score 0):

One not very optimal way of doing it:

```
    dims = size(ND);
    Vrep = repmat(V, [dims(1), dims(2), dims(3), 1]);
    ND_V_dist = sqrt(sum(abs(ND.^2-Vrep.^2), 4));
    iI = find(ND_V_dist==0);
    [I1, I2, I3] = ind2sub([dims(1), dims(2), dims(3)], iI);
```